# How to compile in 32 bit assembly?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, assembly, x86

Hey I use a function of 32 assembly in my c Code. I compile it with nasm and gcc.

```
nasm -f coff array1.asm
gcc -o array1 array1.o array1c.c
```

I always get the error:

```
A
array1c.c:9:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
 int PRE_CDECL asm_main( void ) POST_CDECL;
 ^~~
array1c.c:10:1: warning: ‘cdecl’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
 void PRE_CDECL dump_line( void ) POST_CDECL;
 ^~~~
/usr/bin/ld: i386-Architektur der Eingabedatei »array1.o« ist inkompatibel zur Ausgabe i386:x86-64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thats my code:

```
/*
 * Driver file for array1.asm file
 */

#include <stdio.h>

#include "cdecl.h"

int PRE_CDECL asm_main( void ) POST_CDECL;
void PRE_CDECL dump_line( void ) POST_CDECL;

int main()
{
  int ret_status;
  ret_status = asm_main();
  return ret_status;
}

/*
 * function dump_line
 * dumps all chars left in current line from input buffer
 */
void dump_line()
{
  int ch;

  while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    /* null body*/ ;
}
```

Comment: Use `gcc -m32`.

Comment: Note that `cdecl` is the default calling convention, so setting up `cdecl` isn't needed anyway.

Comment: Why do you use `coff` binary format in the assembler output.  Is there any issue with ELF binary format?

Answer (score 2):

You should compile your code as 32-bit with `gcc -m32`, like so:

```
nasm -f coff array1.asm
gcc -m32 -o array1 array1.o array1c.c
```